# Formatting properties on model in validate method

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In an ASP.NET Core MVC project, I have model validation via `IValidatableObject` interface implementation.

I'm considering to update model properties, when validating the model. Eg. removing leading and trailing spaces.

`IValidatableObject` interface's `Validate` method is an instance method, and I have access to all members (good for comparative validation), but also access to update model props here.

I just feel kind of dirty doing it here, but at the same time it would be very convenient, to do cleanup on values before validation, and ensure that I'm sending good values further down the pipeline.

So is it a alright way to go, or should I choose another (what other)?

Comment: I agree that it feels a bit "dirty" - validation should really **only** check if all the rules and constraints are met - it should **NOT** have any side effects of modifying data ....

Comment: Hi @Jesper Jensen， any update here?

Answer (score 0):

Model validation occurs after model binding and it reports errors where data doesn't conform to business rules. So it is better for you to modify the data when model binding.

A simple demo you could follow to learn how they work:

Model

```
  public class Test:IValidatableObject
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(TrimModelBinder))]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
          
          if (Name=="hello")
          {
              yield return new ValidationResult(
                 $"The Name is not unique.",
                 new[] { nameof(Name) });
          }
      }
  }
```

Custom Model Binding

```
public class TrimModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString))
            {
                // Trim the string
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(valueAsString.Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                // Set an empty string if the value is null or whitespace
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(string.Empty);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

View
@model Test

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <input asp-for="Id" />
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Test model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```